# decompile marshaled java object

Tags: java

I have a java decompiler program `jd-gui.exe` which decompiles the jar/class files, it works perfect, but I have a marshaled object inside the jar file that `jd-gui.exe` cannot understand it.

the question is, is it possible to decompile the marshaled java object?! I mean unmarshal the object into class file then decompile it.

thanks in advance.

EDIT: the marshaled object is kinda serialized object

Comment: When you say marshalled java object, what do you mean? A marshalled object (= JAXB?), a serialized object (= Java Serialization API), a somewhat "special" class file? I mean without any specific information it is damn hard giving a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that when you talk about marshalled objects, you mean objects that have been serialised using the Java Object Serialization subsystem.

A serialization contains the state of the object(s), together with their type signatures.  It does not include the bytecodes for the objects' methods.  So the answer to your question is that it is not possible ... unless you have the bytecodes elsewhere in the JAR file.

---

FWIW - I'm not aware of any serialization scheme for Java in which the bytecodes are embedded in the serial form.  So the above answer probably applies in the general case.

Comment: *You* don’t know of any serialization scheme for Java with that feature, so there can’t be any? Interesting point of view. By the way, the question is about RMI and RMI *is* capable of loading byte code through the network. It’s not embedded in the serialized data but nobody says that embedding is the only way to achieve it.

Comment: @Holger - I didn't say that there can't be.  Please read my answer again.  (The "general case" being for implementations of serialization apart from those written to disprove that it is impossible ... 'cos people wouldn't accept a format loaded down with embedded bytecodes!)  I am aware of RMI and its ability to side-load code.  But my reading is that the Question is specifically about the case where the code >>is<< embedded.

Comment: I don’t see that the question is referring to embedded byte code at all. It’s not really clear what the questioner thinks but to me it looks simply like the situation that the classes are not in the regular class path which *is possible* with RMI. Of course, it is still possible that the questioner is not being able to tell a stream of serialized objects and class byte code apart. But anyway, while it would be possible to give advice for the situation I have in mind, I never give advice for using decompilers especially to users with low reputation so we can end the discussion here…